# pass variable in symfony form builForm Function

Tags: php, symfony

I have tried this code in my controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CentrexEdit2Type($ids), $centrex);
```

I want now to add the `ids` form to my Form Builder:

```
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
          $ids = $options['ids']; 
          .......
```

I failed on it
Any ideas please?

Here I am joining the code:

```
   if ($step==2){
        $form = $this->createForm(new CentrexEdit1Type(), $centrex);
        $ids=$form->get('bases')->getData();
        }

        foreach($ids as $id){echo($id->getId());}
        if ($step==3){
         $form = $this->createForm(new CentrexEdit2Type(array('ids'=>$ids)), $centrex);
        }
```

I need `$ids` when `$step==3`, this is the problem.

Comment: did you try the answers below?

Comment: yes I tried the second one @Bernat

Comment: if you try mine, it will work. i'm using it right now in my website.

Comment: have you seen the code I have just joined?
actually I get the $ids value when $step==2 and I need it also when $step==3 @Bernat

Comment: whoa. I was just answering the title of the question. For other questions, open another thread.

Comment: this has finally worked thanks  lot @Bernat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I do is create the form this way:

> $form = $this->createForm(new TheForm($anArray), $client);

where `$anArray` is an array.

Then, in the form I do something like:

```
public $anArray;

public function __construct($anArray)
{
    $this->anArray = $anArray;
}
```

after this, inside the form class I access the array with `$this->anArray`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CentrexEdit2Type(array('ids'=>$ids)), $centrex);
```

in your controller

and modify your form with

```
protected $ids;
public function __construct(array $parameters=Null)
{
  if($parameters)
  {
    if(array_key_exists('ids',$parameters)) $this->ids = $parameters['ids'];   
  }
}
```

last step

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $ids = $this->ids; 
  [...] 
}
```

Comment: thank u for the answer. It helped me quiet well. But now I want to get the $ids variable in the controller because I get i in an if clause please have a look on my code, I will join it